# How I can run a Naive Bayes categoriser with new data

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to work out how I can run a Naive Bayes categoriser with new data.  All the examples I seem to be able to find are showing how a already classified data can be split into train & test, then run against the test to compare the accuracy.

How do I train the model with classified data and then run it on new data that has not already been classified?

```
df.head()

Ticket ID   Subject Group
Created time            
2017-12-14 15:45:10 12839   ( # 95911231 ) atla of live australia forward ...    
ALA Support
2017-12-14 15:50:12 12840   speci name  ALA Support
2017-12-14 15:53:42 12841   sign up ALA Support
2017-12-14 15:55:40 12842   ( # 182383760 ) atla of live australia forward...    
ALA Support
2017-12-14 16:45:27 12843   test that data_manag forward work   ALA Data Management

encoder = LabelEncoder()
y = encoder.fit_transform(df['Group'])

# process the field
df['Subject'] = df['Subject'].map(lambda x: x.lower())
df['Subject'] = df['Subject'].apply(nltk.word_tokenize)

stemmer = PorterStemmer()

df['Subject'] = df['Subject'].apply(lambda x: [stemmer.stem(y) for y in x])
df['Subject'] = df['Subject'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))

count_vect = CountVectorizer()
counts = count_vect.fit_transform(df['Subject'])

transformer = TfidfTransformer().fit(counts)

counts = transformer.transform(counts)  

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(counts, df['Group'], test_size=0.1, random_state=69)
model = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train, y_train)

predict = model.predict(X_test)

score = model.score(X_test,y_test)
print('Accuracy: {}'.format(score))
```

Thank you in advance.

Regards
Kheeran

---

@RahulAgarwal thanks.  I assume what I need to do is the following to load new data,

```
df = df2
encoder = LabelEncoder()
y = encoder.fit_transform(df['Group'])

# process the field
df['Subject'] = df['Subject'].map(lambda x: x.lower())
df['Subject'] = df['Subject'].apply(nltk.word_tokenize)

stemmer = PorterStemmer()

df['Subject'] = df['Subject'].apply(lambda x: [stemmer.stem(y) for y in x])
df['Subject'] = df['Subject'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))

count_vect = CountVectorizer()
counts = count_vect.fit_transform(df['Subject'])

transformer = TfidfTransformer().fit(counts)

counts = transformer.transform(counts)  

predict2 = model.predict(counts)
```

However when I do I get the following 'dimension mismatch' error,

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-121-7008c135e000> in <module>
     19 counts = transformer.transform(counts)
     20 
---> 21 predict2 = model.predict(counts)

~/analysis-toolkit/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py in predict(self, X)
     64             Predicted target values for X
     65         """
---> 66         jll = self._joint_log_likelihood(X)
     67         return self.classes_[np.argmax(jll, axis=1)]
     68 

~/analysis-toolkit/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py in _joint_log_likelihood(self, X)
    729 
    730         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr')
--> 731         return (safe_sparse_dot(X, self.feature_log_prob_.T) +
    732                 self.class_log_prior_)
    733 

~/analysis-toolkit/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/extmath.py in safe_sparse_dot(a, b, dense_output)
    166     """
    167     if sparse.issparse(a) or sparse.issparse(b):
--> 168         ret = a * b
    169         if dense_output and hasattr(ret, "toarray"):
    170             ret = ret.toarray()

~/analysis-toolkit/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in __mul__(self, other)
513 
514             if other.shape[0] != self.shape[1]:
--> 515                 raise ValueError('dimension mismatch')
516 
517             result = self._mul_multivector(np.asarray(other))

ValueError: dimension mismatch
```

Comment: `predict = model.predict("your new data")`

Comment: @RahulAgarwal, thanks, I did what I assume is the right way to prepare the new data and try to predict, however I get a 'dimension mismatch' error.  I've updated the question with more details.

Comment: This generally happens when the columns in train set is different from New data. Please chk!!

Comment: Hmm, thanks, that was helpful to know.  Yes it is different, but how do I fix it?  The set of words are different in the 2nd set, so when it is vectorized it has different number of columns.  How do I make it merge the original set with the new set?


Original count,

    `<800x1112 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
     with 4554 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>`

2nd time,

    `<691x929 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
     with 3494 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>`

Comment: I dont think it is because of new words in the datasetm that naive bayes would take care of!! I was talking about the raw data which you have passed when making the model and the new_data on which you are testing. Also, read about storing your model as `pickle` file and then applying it to new dataset

Comment: Thank you for your help @RahulAgarwal.  The two dfs have the same number of columns, so that can't be the problem.  First df has the following columns `Index(['Ticket ID', 'Subject', 'Group'], dtype='object')`, second has the following `Index(['Ticket ID', 'Subject', 'Group'], dtype='object')`.

Comment: Try the second option and see if it is working.. Or is the problem solved

Comment: No Rahul, problem isn't solved yet.  :(  Which second option are you referring to?

Comment: Pickle file one

Comment: @RahulAgarwal, ok thanks that worked.  No idea still as to why, but it seems to have fixed the issue and the count values now have the same number of columns.

Comment: You have to read upon it.. But this is how you apply any model on the new data set. If you don't mind can i put my comments as the answer and you can upvote adn accept it for future users!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To try the model on the new dataset:

```
predict = model.predict("your new data")
```

Then save your model into a `pickle` file and use that pickle file to apply the model.